# Target "addoninstall" does not exist in the project "platform"

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

This is regarding Hybris addon install issue.

I'm facing an issue while running `ant addoninstall` command from platform folder.

**Build Failed:**

> Target "addoninstall" does not exist in the project "platform".

What I did was:

1. Created an extension using `ant extgen`.
2. Added the extension name in `localextensions.xml`
3. ran `ant all`
4. ran from platform folder:

   ```
   ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="hartest" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="yacceleratorstorefront"
   ```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

What you are currently try to do is to install the addon 'hartest' on the yacceleratorstorefront. The -Daddonnames parameter needs the name of the add-on you want to install on a extension. For example the 'secureportaladdon' is a correct one.

BR

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if it is the solution, but you should replace the yacceleratorstorefront value with your storefront extension name.

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="hartest" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="mystorefront"
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you run the ant addoninstall command, Ensure that the addonsupport extension is listed in localextensions.xml file

```
...
<extension name="addonsupport"/>
...
```

Also, ensure that the AddOn and storefront extension that you want to install are listed in localextensions.xml file.

then run the command

```
ant addoninstall -Daddonnames="hartest" -DaddonStorefront.yacceleratorstorefront="yacceleratorstorefront"
```

But you should create your own storefront extension and install addon on custom extension rather than directly on template and make sure you choose yaddon template while creating your custom addon.